# deleteing a list of values sent from client

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to delete a list of values from database.I create a list with JQ and send it to server. my problem is how can I extract the values with request method my JQ code looks like this :

```
$("#del").click(function () {
    var dellist = "";
    $(".del:checked").each(function () {
        dellist += "'" + $(this).val() + "',";
    })
    dellist += "''";
    $.get("mem.aspx?cmd=del&dellist=" + dellist, function () { });
})
```

and the C# part is like this :

```
if(CMD == "del")
{ 

}
```

I use entity framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as you are making query string in get method.

```
string del = Request.QueryString["del"].ToString();
string  dellist = Request.QueryString["dellist"].ToString();
```

You can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to extract values from server.

```
string []listValues = Request.QueryString["dellist"].ToString().Split(',');
```

Comment: yes i did that, here is what i did: string dellist = Request.QueryString[1]; and now i get a list of value i just dont know how to extract the value

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
string cmd=Request["cmd"];
string  dellist = Request["dellist"];
```

Comment: It's important to note that this approach will query the `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, and `ServerVariables` collections in that order. If you don't know that, you could be in for some surprises in the future! See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String[] dellist = Request.QueryString["dellist"].Split(',');
```

since you have string with comma separated you can split that string with `,` character as above. String.Split method return array of strings.